# First few smallest eigenvalues of a large dense symmetric matrix

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I construct a large (say 2000x2000) matrix `M` whose entries are real random variables drawn from a certain distribution. Most of these values will be nonzero, so `M` is **not** sparse. Then I construct (formally)

`X[i,j] = ( M[i,j] + M[j,i] ) / 2;`

so that I know for sure that the matrix `X` is symmetric.

I am interested in the first few (say 10) eigenvalues of `X`, smallest in absolute value. I checked the Documentation and I tested

```
Eigenvalues[X];
Eigenvalues[X, -10]; 
Eigenvalues[matrix, -10, Method -> "Arnoldi"];
Eigenvalues[matrix,Method->{"FEAST","Interval"->{min,max}}];
```

Supposedly the first basic method should be the slowest, because it's giving me the list of *all* the eigenvalues. It turns out this is not the case: the first two methods take just about the same time, while the 3rd and the 4th are definitely slower.

What is going on? And, most importantly, what is the fastest method to get to my goal?

Comment: The third method is  about 15% faster for me (13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021).  I don't have the FEAST library installed to check the 4th.  I used `SeedRandom[0];
x = With[{m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2000, 2000}]},
   (m + Transpose[m])/2];`

Comment: I'm running my code on a Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8. Could it be that Mathematica is parallelizing parts of the first algorithm, so that it turns out to be faster on my machine?

Comment: I also found that the Arnoldi method is the fastest of the three, but by a relatively small margin (0.52 s vs.  0.53 s vs. 0.51 s). I am on MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64.

Comment: I also have 8 cores. I don’t think it is parallelizing. But, I don’t know how to determine whether that is true.

Comment: @CraigCarter I use Linux and if I type `top` in a terminal while Mathematica is running, I find a CPU usage of, like, 200%. Then I guess it is parallelizing.

Comment: I also looked at top.  I didn’t know that cpu > 100% meant parallel.

Comment: (For simplicity, I assume we are looking for one eigenvalue only.) So you have a real symmetric matrix `X`. Is `X` positive definite? If yes, then smallest absolute value is the same as smallest, and can use an iterative method, such as power or Arnoldi/Lanczos, whose speed will depend a lot (!) on how big the gap between the smallest eigenvalue and the others is. If not, meaning you are looking for an eigenvalue in the middle of the spectrum, then you could apply an iterative method to the inverse matrix (use `LinearSolve[X]`). I am not a numerical analyst, so take this with a grain of salt.